# Why doesn’t Selenium find an element with this XPath expression?

Tags: python, selenium, chrome-web-driver

I’m trying to find an element with this XPath expression:

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/input
```

But Selenium can’t find one.

The page I’m trying to access - https://account.aax.com/en-US/login/

I already tried to follow this path by myself, and it’s fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing a delay. `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` should be used for that.
2. You have to improve your locators.

The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url = "https://account.aax.com/en-US/login/"

driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input']"))).click()
```

Comment: I use for this `driver.implicitly_wait(5)`
isnt this what you mean?

Comment: In case you trying to click that element or send a text there this is not enough since `implicitly_wait` sets timeout for element presence only while we need to find the element on more mature stage, when it able to accept click etc. i.e. fully rendered.